# add two splash screen with .gif and normal image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two images for splash image in which one is simple image and second one is .gif file. If app open only first time, i want to show .gif file as splash screen. If app isn't open first time,i want to show normal images as splash screen.
how can do this by code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, `AppDelegate's` **`Life Cycle Methods`**, to determine when you want to show what.. Use these methods..

You can easily use a `BOOL` to determine whether your app is in running state of killed state, see below

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    wasInBackground=YES;
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
   if(wasInBackground){
       //Notify to show splash screen using simple image

      wasInBackground=NO;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Cheers.